# PHP Script results in Server Timeout

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a script which reads a lot of data from the database. The script itself gets triggered by another script. (To ensure the script will not run twice or more times)
 Unfortunately I keep running into a server timeout.
I tried to solve it with

```
    set_time_limit(0);
```

and

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

but that didn't do the trick.
What the scirpt does is, it generates a CSV file which then should be downloaded by the user ( via browser ).
The file itself has to be created just in time, so I cannot create it during night and push it or anything like this.
Is there something like a best-practise? 
Since I cannot change the generating script itself, how can I ensure, the file gets generated and the user gets informed that the file is ready for download?
(I can't use mail)?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's possible the web-server also has its own timeout you need to change.

Comment: What server gives a timeout? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Check for infinite loops or database query optimizations. If you can share code, we'll help more.

Comment: 1) I cannot change the timeout of the server. 2) Gateway Timeout
The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.3) I can asure there's no infinite loops and the queries have been optimized, I think the way to go would be: Script A tells Script B to run - When Script B is finished tell Script A to echo a successmessage. But I cant figure out how that second step might work.